# SwiftUI contextMenu Mac Catalyst compatibility

Tags: ios, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I cannot get the SwiftUI api `contextMenu(menuItems:)` to work when I build for Mac Catalyst. The [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/contextmenu(menuitems:)) say it is compatible with Mac Catalyst 13+. It works fine on iOS, however, when I build for Catalyst it does nothing. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What does "does nothing" mean? On Mac, it will be revealed by right- or ctrl-clicking.

Comment: Ah thanks so much. I was doing a long press on Mac and that does nothing. Right click works.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I was doing a long press. That only works on iOS. On Mac, one should do a right click.